# Retrieving the results in mysql and format it

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have a column col1, which contains 5 fixed values
I used a byte field to represent each value in ms sql server

```
1-value1...5-value5
```

when I execute the select query, what I am getting is the byte value in gridview

Is there a way so that i can change the output to show the value?

Instead of showing 1 in gridview, I should see value1 in gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MySQL's CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement to print the string representation instead of the byte value. In case your byte has bits set, one for each value, then you would need to use the bitwise AND to see if a particular bit is set and then print the appropriate string representation. Did I missing something, otherwise?

Comment: I am using a tinyint for the col 1 in sql server, so I have to use a stored procedure and output the field?

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure, you need to replace the tinyint column in your select list with the case statement.